# LDAP authentication with Worklight using email field instead of UID

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

I am currently trying to authenticate mobile application users using a LDAP loginModule with Worklight.

Instead of using the UID property as the username, I want to authenticate users by their email adress (field "mail" in an LDAP user entry).

I read the IBM Worklight documentation and follow the tutorial but I don't really understand how to do that with a LDAP login module. 
I have tried this loginModule configuration :

```
<loginModule name="LDAPLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
        <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://localhost:389"/>
        <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
        <parameter name="validationType" value="searchPattern"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="{username}"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchFilterPattern" value="(mail={username})"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com"/>
    </loginModule>
```

But the LDAP returns an error 409 : invalid credentials.

Have you an idea to help me ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you able to login with UID with the same code? By using `(uid={username})`

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use the UID to login and change by (uid={username}) but it's not working. Actually, I don't really understand the use of the "ldapSecurityAuthentication" parameter

Comment: AFAIK it is a authentication security type. For more info see these links [link1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/simple.html) [link2](http://www.isode.com/whitepapers/strong-auth-dir.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) to get know Worklight related sample projects with sample projects.

You can find LDAP example project also under `Authentication and security`

AFAIK

- simple ldapSecurityAuthentication used to send  password with fully qualified DN as clear text and it uses LDAP_Simple_ Bind request to connect to LDAP server
- Strong ldapSecurityAuthentication is a much stronger authentication method that can require a signed certificate or other method of authenticating the user.

Am not sure about None option for ldapSecurityAuthentication.

The above info's i got it from LDAP admin. Am also new to LDAP

Comment: Read the question. He wrote he did just that. He is asking about specific LDAP properties...

Comment: @IdanAdar he added a comment saying he wants sameple project. So only shared the link. But after that he removed it seems. Now updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers which help me a lot to understand.

The application requirements changed in the beginning of the week and I need now to authenticate users with the UID.
I have succeeded with this configuration :

```
<loginModule name="LDAPLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
        <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://localhost:389"/>
        <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
        <parameter name="validationType" value="searchPattern"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="uid={username},OU=people,DC=mycompany,DC=com"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchFilterPattern" value="(uid={username})"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="OU=people,DC=mycompany,DC=com"/>
    </loginModule>
```

It's work very well, so my problem is resolved.

However, to resolve this post, I am still trying to authenticate users with e-mail adress but I don't know how to do this. Maybe the only solution is to use a custom authentication module and to use a LDAP Java library ?

Thanks a lot.